# Como identificar valor alterado em input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como identificar se um determinando valor foi alterado no `input`? Possuo o protótipo abaixo, contudo o `alert` será exibido de acordo com o número de vezes que a `class="ultimo-valor"` aparece no código.

```
<input class="ultimo-valor" onKeyUp="ultimoValor(this)" type="text" 
value="<?php echo $ultimo_valor; ?>"/>

<input class="ultimo-valor" onKeyUp="ultimoValor(this)" type="text" 
value="<?php echo $ultimo_valor; ?>"/>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
   function ultimoValor(e) {
      $('.ultimo-valor').on("change paste keyup", function() {
       alert($(this).val());
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Esta dando algum erro? Nao esta funcionando?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/teuwLswp/

Comment: @LocalHost, o `alert` deverá ser exibido somente uma única vez para cada alteração.

Comment: publiquei uma resposta, ve se é isso

Comment: @LocalHost, obrigado pela ajuda. Não sei se expus o problema claramente, mas o MarceloBonifazio respondeu corretamente.

Comment: Acredito que as respostas não ficaram tão diferentes. Mas que bom que obteve o resultado esperado :)

Comment: Consegue alterá-la para mais de um `input`?

Comment: Sim... editei ali, eu tinha retirado apenas para ficar melhor de visualizar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou assumindo que procura uma resposta que funcione com `javascript` puro ou com `jquery`.... (são as tags referenciadas na pergunta)

```js
var ultimovalor = 8;

function verifica_valor(element) {
  if (ultimovalor != element.value) {
    alert("Alterou!\nNovo valor: "+element.value); 
    ultimovalor = element.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onchange="verifica_valor(this)" type="text" value="20" />

<input onchange="verifica_valor(this)" type="text" value="10" />
```

Comment: Marcelo obrigado pela resposta. AH, `JavaScript` é uma linguagem e `jQuery` é uma biblioteca do `JavaScript`.

Comment: @luccasrodrigo sim eu sei, acho que não me expressei bem :)

Answer (score 3):

Seria assim?
Ao carregar o documento, guardo o valor do campo na variavel `valor` e ao efetuar a alteração do campo, verifico se ficou diferente do valor que esta armazenado na variave. Se esta diferente  emito o `alert` e altero o valor da variavel `valor`que contem o valor atual do campo.

Veja funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variavel que recebe o valor atual ao carregar a pagina
  var valor = $(this).val();
  // funcao que é executada ao carregar a pagina
  $('.ultimo-valor').on("change paste keyup", function() {
    // verifica se o valor esta diferente do campo
    if (valor != $(this).val()) {
      // aqui o valor foi alterado
      alert($(this).val());
      //atualiza o valor da variavel
      valor = $(this).val();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="ultimo-valor" type="text" value="" />
<input class="ultimo-valor" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: [+1]. Grato pela alternativa.